# I want to load a component inside of a tag which also uses the innerHTML directive

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I'm trying to use the innerHTML directive as well as trying to load a component  in to that same tag.

An example:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of array">
    <li [innerHTML]="item.listItemHtml">
        <app-some-component [someInput]='item.componentInput'><app-some-component>
    </li>
</ul>
```

so the end result should look something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>list item 1</span>
        <span>component input text 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>list item 2</span>
        <span>component input text 2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm still relatively new to angular so I'm trying to get the hang of things. If anyone could give me some insight on how I might be able to achieve this.. that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the component inside of the parent element if you also bind the `innerHTML` property. The element will contain only the HTML set by the `innerHTML` binding.

You can achieve what you want by setting the `outerHTML` property of a child element (a sibling of the component). It can be a `div`, a `span` or another type of element; it will be replaced with the bound HTML content anyway.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of array">
  <li>
    <div [outerHTML]="item.listItemHtml"></div>
    <app-some-component [someInput]='item.componentInput'><app-some-component>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hb5xd6) for a demo.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!